# How can I get the current route/path with typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

With normal react it would just be this.props.location.pathname. How do I do that with typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap component in withRouter and merge it's props with RouteComponentProps from 'react-router-dom', also it accepts Generic which represents route params.

Comment: Thanks, that worked but now defaultProps doesnt work anymore. Any idea why?